# An alternative proof for $D_2 D_1 f(x) = D_1 D_2 f(x)$ when $f \in C^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

In [the book](http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/~papadim/calculus_on_manifolds/Munkres.pdf) of *Analysis On Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 103, question 4-b, it is asked to show that

> $$D_2 D_1 f(x) = D_1 D_2 f(x)$$ for all $x \in A$, where $A \subseteq
>  \mathbb{R}^2 $ is open and $f\in C^2(A)$.

### Proof:

Let $Q$ be a rectangle in $A$, so we do know that 
$$\int_Q D_2 D_1 f(x) = \int_Q D_1 D_2 f(x),$$
hence consider 
$$\int_Q |D_2 D_1 f(x) - D_1 D_2 f(x)| = $$
Since the integral above exists, and the integrand is non-negative and the integral is zero, by a theorem, the integrand $|D_2 D_1 f(x) - D_1 D_2 f(x)|$ vanishes except on a a set of measure zero.

Now we claim that, the integrand $|D_2 D_1 f(x) - D_1 D_2 f(x)|$ vanishes everywhere on $Q$.

Assume that is it not the case; then $\exists a \in Q$ s.t $|D_2 D_1 f(a) - D_1 D_2 f(a)| \not = 0$, so by a lemma, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ s.t that the integrand is still non-zero, but that contradicts with the fact that the integrand vanishes on $Q$ except on a set of measure zero, since a open ball does not have a measure zero.

So, $|D_2 D_1 f(x) - D_1 D_2 f(x)| = 0$ $\forall x \in Q$ implies 
$$D_2 D_1 f(x) = D_1 D_2 f(x) \quad \forall x \in Q.$$

### Question:

Is there any flaw in my proof ? or is there anything that is not clear ? or do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: "Since the integral above exists, and the integrand is non-negative and the integral is zero" Why is the integral zero?

Comment: @Chappers because the integral of each term is equal to one another, so the integral of their difference has to be zero.

Comment: But $\int f = 0 \not\Rightarrow \int \lvert f \rvert = 0$.

Comment: @Chappers Yeah, I know. It is pointed out in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f \in C^2(A)$, the function $g =D_2D_1f - D_1D_2f$ is continuous.

Choose any point $a \in A$.   If $g(a) > 0$, then there exists a rectangle $Q$ such that $g(x) > 0 $ for all $x \in Q$ and $\int_Qg  > 0$, contradicting

$$\int_Q D_2D_1f = \int_QD_1D_2 f.$$

Make a similar argument if $g(a) < 0$, proving that $g(a) = 0$ for all $a \in A$.

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed a big flaw in your proof:

$$\int f =0$$ doesn’t imply that $$\int \vert f \vert=0$$ which is basically what you’re using.

Comment: It is asked to prove in question $4-a$, which I have shown.

Comment: What is question 4-a? Can you write it? Certainly, you haven’t proved that $\int f=0$ implies $\int \vert f\vert =0$.

Comment: I have put the link of the book. You can check out from there. I do not want to state that theorem in the question because it distracts the reader, I think

Comment: question 4−a doesn't imply by any means that from $\int f =0$ you can get $\int |f| =0$.

Comment: @Bob No. But that is what the OP is using for the proof of 4-b. See the question.

Comment: Yes, but it seems that the OP thinks that by question 4-a you can get, from $\int f=0$, that $\int|f|=0$, while the whole point is that $f$ has a definite sign if $Q$ is sufficiently small.